# Does WebStorm not run to breakpoints on an await line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I first set a breakpoint on the let line, the if statement line, and the await line.

Assuming I break on the let line and then press run to next breakpoint, the code does hit the next breakpoint.

However, if I'm on the let line, I can press step over and go to the `const test` line, hit step over again, and it jumps over the if statement and goes to the `const test2` line. Pushing run does not lead to the await line and pushing step over or into after reaching test2 results in me going into other code.

As a former Visual Studio user this is really strange behavior to me. I don't know if it's a TypeScript peculiarity or something to do with TypeScript/JavaScript and the async/await construct.

I've rebuilt several times just to verify that my code matches what's running on the server.

I thought that await line should get hit, then it should suspend the rest of the function.

```
public async requestList() {

    let res = this.cache.get(serializedParam);

    const test = 'test';
    if (!res) {
        const test2 = 'test2';
        const _res = await Function(param);
     }
```

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39041, please follow it for updates

Comment: you seem to be right, but I can't accept a comment as the answer. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong, but it's just because of the typescript source mapping to javascript. Anyway it is something to be aware of. it's frustrating to suddenly jump to a section of code and not know for certain what has run and what hasn't

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks similar to [WEB-39041](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39041), please follow it for updates. It only occurs when using sourcemaps, stepping works fine when debugging pure Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Declare the function as 'async' in order to use await. The function needs tobe async.

```
async requestList() {
    let res = this.cache.get(serializedParam);

    const test = 'test';
    if (!res) {
        const test2 = 'test2';
        const _res = await Function(param);
     }
}

async  Function(param){

}
```